# Сортировка массива по значению

Tags: массивы, php

```
Array(
    array(
       'name' => 'title 1',
       'price' => '200'
    )
    array(
       'name' => 'title 2',
       'price' => '100'
    )
    ...
)
```

У меня есть такой массив. Как мне его сортировать по значению ключа `price`, от меньшего к большему?

Comment: @chuikoff, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Кстати сказать, можно воспользоваться функцией array_multisort, подробнее см статью https://intsystem.org/coding/sortirovka-mnogomernyh-massivov-po-klyuchu-na-php/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Сортировка пользовательской функцией: [usort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ($a['price'] - $b['price']);
});
```

Comment: А как эту функцию забахать в шаблон smarty?

Comment: Стоит ли это делать в представлении? Передавайте уже отсортированный массив, либо сортируйте JavaScript'ом. 

А вообще, если очень хочется:

    {php} /* PHP-код */ {/php}

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = array
( 
    array( 'name' => 'title 1', 'price' => 200 ),
    array( 'name' => 'title 2', 'price' => 100 )
);

usort
( 
    $data,
    create_function
    (   
        '$a,$b', 
        'return -($a["price"] - $b["price"]);' #возврат нужного значения
    )
);
```

1) не забываем, что поля price должны быть int, а не строками (в противном случае нужно явное преобразование)

2) если нужно обратный порядок сортировки:

```
return $a["price"] - $b["price"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Можешь преобразовать его в массив вида:

array('200' => 'title1', '100' => 'title2') и отсортировать стандартной функцией php ksort(или другой, какой захочешь)

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл на просторах интернета:

```
function cmp($a, $b){ 
  return strnatcmp($a["product_order"], $b["product_order"]); 
} 
usort($parts, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

функция uasort предназначена для сортировки с помощью пользовательской функции, но с сохранением ключей массива (в отличие от usort).

Answer (score 0):

мучился долго с похожей проблемой, вот мое решение:

принцип:

- строим еще один массив "2" где ключ нового массива = ключ старого, а само значение = значение по которому хотим сортировать;
- сортируем новый массив "2" СОХРАНЯЯ КЛЮЧИ (asort, arsort);
- ну и далее строим еще один массив "3" на основе массива "2" - проходим по массиву "2" и по ходу вставляем в массив "3" "подмассив" массива "1" по ключу массива "2";
- массив "3" и есть наш отсортированный.

```php
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    $sortkey[$i]=$array[$i]['price'];
}

asort($sortkey);//по возрастанию, arsort($sortkey) - по убыванию

foreach ($sortkey as $key => $key) {
    $sorted[]=$array[$key];
}
```

Comment: В итоге у вас будет создано на 2 массива больше, чем в ответах других участников. Расскажите, пожалуйста, чем ваш алгоритм лучше.