# Пользовательская сортировка

Tags: php

Продолжение [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138791/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E).
Необходимо сделать функцию, чтобы другие пользователи смогли сортировать по полю которое им нужно. Делаю я это так:

```
function sort_page($pages,$field,$sort)
{
    usort($pages,function($a,$b)
    {
        return ($a[$field] - $b[$field]);
    });

    return $pages;
}
```

В шаблоне вызываю следующим образом:

```
{$pages = sort_page($pages,'field_price','desc')}
```

Отправляю массив, поле по которому нужно сортировать, и порядок сортировки (в примере не используется). Если пишу

```
return ($a['field_price'] - $b['field_price']);
```

То всё работает отлично, если так как в примере то не работает. Как-будто функция внутри usort не принимает другие переменные. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
function sort_page($pages,$field,$sort)
{
    usort($pages,function($a,$b)use($field)
    {
        return ($a[$field] - $b[$field]);
    });
    return $pages;
}
```

В PHP замыкание переменных на анонимную функцию нужно указывать явно через `use`.

Comment: А вот это, правильный ответ! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

[Смотрим работу кода тут](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/c13-d1n) (Для запуска жмём "**Run**")

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'title 1','price' => '200'),
    array('name' => 'title 2','price' => '100'),
    array('name' => 'title 3','price' => '500'),
    array('name' => 'title 4','price' => '30')
);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key]  = $row['name'];
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}

array_multisort($price, SORT_NUMERIC, $name,  $data);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но у меня массив не такой, там ещё куча полей. name и price я для примера сделал. Мне просто интересно почему в той функции не читается переменная. Может её стоит сделать global или ещё-что?