# Как правильно отсортировать многомерный массив

Tags: php

есть многомерный массив

```
Array=>[
    0 => [
      'id'=>'1'
    ],
    1 =>[
       'id' =>'2'
    ],
    2 =>[
       'id' =>'100'
    ]
]
```

пытаюсь отсортировать его следующим образом

```
uasort($arr,function ($a, $b){return strcmp((int) $a['id'], (int) $b['id']);});
var_dump($arr['id']);
```

получаю

```
 0 => string '1' 
 1 => string '100' 
 2 => string '2'
```

можно ли как то отсортировать так

```
  0 => string '1' 
  1 => string '2' 
  2 => string '100'
```

Вопрос в оперировании цифрами или строками а не как вообще сортировать массив

Comment: ну так и сортируйте **по числам**, а не по строкам через `strcmp` ..... то есть `uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {return (int)$a['id'] - (int)$b['id']; })`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Пишите ответ

Comment: @Visman вы не видите разницу между int и string ? В чем дубликат?

Comment: В обоих случаях реализация идет с помощью функции usort(), так что нет ни какой разницы между вопросами. А то, что вы напишите в анонимной функции - это уже частности. P.S. Тот код который вы показываете в своем вопросе не вернет того, что написано у вас в `получаю`. P.P.S. Функция uasort() сохраняет ключи, так что сортируйте через нее или не сортируйте, ключи останутся одни и те же у значений из входящего и исходящего массивов :Р Читайте мануалы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный вопрос уже задавался: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/138802/18476

```
$arr = array(array('id'=>'100'),array('id' =>'1'),array('id' =>'2'));

print_r($arr);

uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {return (int)$a['id'] - (int)$b['id']; });

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
        )

)
```