# Сортировка двумерного массива по ключу

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть двумерный массив:

```
array(7) {
 [0]=>
  array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(529)
  [1]=>
  string(5) "40.00"
         }
 [1]=>
   array(4) {
   [0]=>
   int(525)
   [1]=>
   string(5) "50.00"

   ...
}
```

Необходимо отсортировать данный массив по ключу `[1]` (т.е по элементам 40.00, 50.00) в обратном порядке. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php  пробовали?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка массива по значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138791/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не совсем понял, как в обратном порядке отсортировать

Comment: @r.mcreal поменять местами `$a`  и `$b` например)) или знаки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
   array( 
       539,
       "40.00"
   ),
   array(
       525,
       "50.00"
   )
  );

usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return $a[1] < $b[1]; // в обратном порядке - $a[1] > $b[1];
});

/*
output
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 525 
        [1] => 50.00 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 539 
        [1] => 40.00 
    ) 
)
*/
```

Comment: А как в обратном порядке?

Comment: добавил в ответ.